# How to give each URL its own threading

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have been working on a small PoC where I have been trying to improve my knowledge with Threading but unfortunately I got stuck and here I am,

```
import time

found_products = []

site_catalog = [
    "https://www.graffitishop.net/Sneakers",
    "https://www.graffitishop.net/T-shirts",
    "https://www.graffitishop.net/Sweatshirts",
    "https://www.graffitishop.net/Shirts"
]


def threading_feeds():
    # Create own thread for each URL as we want to run concurrent
    for get_links in site_catalog:
        monitor_feed(link=get_links)


def monitor_feed(link: str) -> None:
    old_payload = product_data(...)

    while True:
        new_payload = product_data(...)

        if old_payload != new_payload:
            for links in new_payload:
                if links not in found_products:
                    logger.info(f'Detected new link -> {found_link} | From -> {link}')
                    # Execute new thread as we don't want to block this function wait for filtering() to be done before continue
                    filtering(link=found_link)

        else:
            logger.info("Nothing new")
            time.sleep(60)
            continue


def filtering(found_link):
    ...
```

1 - Im currently trying to do a monitor where I have multiple links to start with, my plan is that I would like to each url to run concurrently instead of needing to wait 1 by 1:

```
def threading_feeds():
   # Create own thread for each URL as we want to run concurrent
   for get_links in site_catalog:
      monitor_feed(link=get_links)
```

How can I do that?

---

2 - If we seem to find a new product that has appeared to the given URL inside the `monitor_feed`, how can I set a new thread to execute the call `filtering(link=found_link)`? I dont want to wait for it to be done before it continues to loop back for the `While True` but instead it should do the `filtering(link=found_link)` in the background while it stil executes the `monitor_feed`

Comment: Your question talks about Threading, but you have no code which uses Threads. StackOverflow is full of questions about Threading. Which examples did you look at?

Comment: @quamrana Oh im sorry, I have looked into threading.thread(...).start via docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html but I don't think that might be correct? I have not used it before as my knowledge with threading is low in general.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import concurrent.futures    
with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.map(monitor_feed, site_catalog)
```

You can use [ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor).

Comment: Oh right, and what about the `monitor_feed` function where we call the `filtering(link=found_link)`? Wouldn't this wait for it to be done before it continues the while loo?